# Android integration with Mac OS X

Tags: applications, macos, ios

Is there a way to connect Android phone with OS X Yosemite, just like (or similar) iOS does? [Apple - OS X Yosemite - Mac + iOS Continuity](https://www.apple.com/osx/continuity/).

I'm aware of [AirDroid | Delight Your Multi-Screen Life](https://www.airdroid.com/en/), but I'm looking for other alternatives...

Answer (score 0):

For Calendar, Contact  data and other *iTunes sync* features are supported by **AirDroid** as suggested in this *Android Authority article* :[Using Android with Mac OS X: tips and recommendations](http://www.androidauthority.com/use-android-mac-os-x-632616/)

For calls, SMS and other notifications try [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/apps).